# Python: store results of ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm very new to parallel processing with "concurrent.futures". Code seems to work, but I am not sure how to store the result of each process, therey by marking the build as failed at last, if any of processes's return value is not zero.
Tried to create a list (`exit_status`) and append the results to that, but that shows `IndexError`. Wondering what can I do right?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import concurrent.futures
import sys
import shutil
import os
import glob
import multiprocessing as mp
import json
from os import path


def slave(path1, path2, target):
    os.makedirs(target)
    shutil.copy(path1, target)
    shutil.copy(path2, target)
    os.system(<Login command>)
    os.system(<Image creation command>)
    os.system(<Copy to Other slaves or NFS>)
    
    #If any one of the above operation or command fails for any of the process, the script should return 1 at the end of the execution or fail the build at last.


def main():
    processed = {}
    exit_status = []
    with open('example.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for value in data.items():
            for line in value[1]:
                if line.endswith('.zip'):
                    targz = line
                elif line.endswith('.yaml'):
                    yaml = line
            processed[targz] = yaml


    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for id, (path2, path1) in enumerate(processed.items(), 1):
            target = path.join("/tmp", "dir" + str(id))
            ret = executor.submit(slave, path1, path2, target)
            exit_status.append(ret.result())

    for i in exit_status:
    print("##########Result status: ", i)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    main()
```

`exit_status` list's output:

```
 ##########Result status:  None
##########Result status:  None
```

Comment: First, you do not need to call `executor.shutdown()`; that will happen implicitly at the termination of the `with` block. Second, you would normally get your results by iterating all the `Future` instances in `exit_status` and calling method `result` on each one. But I can see that doing so would raise an `IndexError` exception because that exception occurred in function `slave`. Not knowing what your input JSON file looks like and what `slave`  *really* looks like makes it difficult to say why, so you need to figure out why.

Comment: @Booboo : I've fixed the function and updated the question. I', getting `None` as return value now.

Comment: the function you `submit` never returns anything, and any function that doesn't explicitly return something will return `None`

Comment: @Aaron : Yes my `slave` function does, 1. 1st command `repository login` 2. 2nd command as `helm chart creation` 3. and lastly `NFS push`, so it doesn't return anything.
In this scenario, how should I monitor the process or threads to capture the return values ? THanks

Comment: @voltas if you want to check the output, you should probably use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead of `os.system`, then you can return an appropriate value from `slave`

Comment: also, you should gather up a list of your `Future` objects (`ret` in this case) so that they all get submitted before you wait on any results. As is, you're waiting for the result of each operation before submitting the next. (ie: not doing things in parallel)

Comment: @Aaron : How can i do that, gather up a list of `ret` before i wait for results.
I'm not exactly sure, any help would be really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re; comments

If you want to get the result of a system call in order to act on the results of it, using `subprocess.run` is much more flexible and powerful than `os.system`. Additionally, if you actually want to perform the operations in parallel, you can't wait on `result()` after each task. Otherwise you're only ever doing one thing at a time. Better to submit all the tasks, and collect the `Future` objects. Then you can iterate over those and wait on each `result()` now that you've submitted all the work you want the `executor` to do.

```py
def target_func(path1, path2, target):
    #...
    #instead of os.system, use subprocess.run
    
    #you can inspect the stdout from the process
    complete_process = subprocess.run(<Login command>, text=True, capture_output=True)
    if "success" not in complete_process.stdout:
        return "uh-oh"
    #you can also just check the return value (0 typically means clean exit)
    if subprocess.run(<Image creation command>).returncode == 0:
        return "uh-oh"
    #or you can tell `run` to generate an error if the returncode is non-zero
    try:
        subprocess.run(<Copy to Other slaves or NFS>, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return "uh-oh"
    return "we did it!"

def main():
    #...
    #...
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for id, (path2, path1) in enumerate(processed.items(), 1):
            target = path.join("/tmp", "dir" + str(id))
            ret = executor.submit(slave, path1, path2, target)
            exit_status.append(ret)

    for i in exit_status:
        print("##########Result status: ", i.result())
```

Comment: this greatly helps, thanks a bunch ! will build on it :)